# Two Nics, one direct connection and forwarding

Tags: centos, forwarding, nic

I'm designing a system with a Server PC with two nics running Centos 6 and a Sensor Device which runs a web server. The Sensor Device is connected directly to one of the nics of the Server PC. All that is in a box. The other nic is available from outside and can be connected to a switch.

Now, from my PC (or other client) I want to be able to access the Sensor Device web server, but I can't. I'm far from being an expert configuring networks like this. What I want:

When the Client PC request 192.168.1.100:8080 then the Server PC forwards that to 192.168.0.100:80 and then I can see it on the client PC. There are other answers about configuring two nics, bridges, bounding and other things but I don't think is the same situation.

If necessary I could use the same network for both the Server PC and the Sensor Device, but until now that doesn't help.

A diagram with the system is attached (using dropbox as I don't have enough votes, sorry).

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50305647/Two%20nics%20diagram.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple.

1. Allow forwarding on Server PC
2. Add DNAT rules to Server PC

For CentOS it would be:

1. Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and change

   `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0` to `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`,
   then `sysctl -p`
2. `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.100:80`

Also make sure that you have allowing rules in `FORWARD` chain of `input` table in `iptables`.